# eigenvector of 2x2 matrix

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

A = $ \begin{pmatrix} -1 & 1  \\  -1 & -1\end{pmatrix} $

eigenvalues are $-1 + i$ and $-1-i$

I am a bit confused working out the eigenvectors for each eigenvalue, for example

for the second eigenvalue $ \lambda_{2}= -1-i$

I get

$ \begin{pmatrix} i & 1  \\  -1 & i \end{pmatrix} $ $   \begin{pmatrix} x_1   \\  -x_2 \end{pmatrix} $ = $  \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\  0 \end{pmatrix} $

so first equation I get,

$ ix_1 + x_2 = 0 $

$ -x_1+ix_2 = 0 $

from the first equation

$ ix_1 = -x_2 $

$ x_1 = -x_2/i $

so setting $x_2 = -i,  x_1 = 1$

so  $  x_{2} =   \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -i \end{pmatrix} $

but from the second equation I get a differenct eigenvector

$ -x_1 = ix_2 $

if I let $x_2 = 1$ then $x_1=-i$

so I get

$ x_2$ =  $  \begin{pmatrix} -i \\ 1  \end{pmatrix} $

Which eigenvector is correct ?

Answer (score 1):

$x_2$ is a complex number, not a vector. Subsitituting $x_2 = -ix_1$ in the second equation gives $-x_1 -i^2x_1 = 0$, which is always true. So the only constraint is $x_2 = -x_1i$, so any eigenvector is of the form $(x_1, -x_1 i)^T$ for any $x_1\in \mathbb{C}$.

Both vectors you gave (and mislabeled) $x_2$ are eigenvectors. Eigenvectors are not unique.

Comment: Oh okay, so either one would be correct? Also I labelled it x2 because it’s the eigenvector Associated  with the second eigenvalue.

Comment: @italy yes, either is correct. If you need to give all eigenvectors (aka the eigenspace), you need to give it by $\{(\lambda, -\lambda i)^T \ | \ \lambda \in  \mathbb{C}\}$.